# rake procedure and rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this commands sequence into a Rake file

```
  task :compile => :environment do
          system "bundle exec rake assets:clean"
          system "bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production"
          system "chmod 777 -R /var/www/app/tmp/cache/"
          system "/etc/init.d/apache2 restart"
  end
```

let's suppose that one of the command generate an exception, is there a way to perform a rollback over the past commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three firsts can be done in Ruby. Use `Rake::Task['assets:clean'].invoke` for example.
For the last one, you could raise an exception depending of the exit status (system returns it).